# Union of two dictionaries of lists

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create a new dictionary of lists  based on two exiting dictionaries

**Input**

```
dic1 = {'A' :['1','2','3'] , 'B' :['2','3','4'] ,'C' :['5','6','7']}
dic2 = {'A' :['1','2','5'] , 'B' :['5','6','7'] ,'D' :['1','2','3']}
```

**Output**

```
dic3 =  {'A' :['1','2','3','5'] , 'B' :['2','3','4','5','6','7'] ,'C':['5','6','7'],'D':['1','2','3']}
```

**What I tried**

```
dic3 = {key: value + dic2[key] for key, value in dic1.items()}
```

Could you please help me out to get `dic3`? I am getting key error for `'C'` key in `dic1`.

Comment: Have you tried using sets?

Comment: yes  Here it is  : z = { key:x.get(key,[])+y.get(key,[]) for key in set(list(x.keys())+list(y.keys())) }  I am getting duplicate values in the list

Comment: Is the order of items in the lists important?

Comment: no..but i dont need duplicate values in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order of items in the inner lists isn't important:

```
dic3 = {
    key: list(set(dic1.get(key, []) + dic2.get(key, [])))
    for key in dic1.keys() | dic2.keys()
}
print(dic3)
```

Prints:

```
{'C': ['7', '5', '6'], 'D': ['1', '3', '2'], 'A': ['1', '3', '5', '2'], 'B': ['2', '6', '7', '5', '4', '3']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use method `.get` to extract values. It does not fail when a key is not in the dictionary:

```
{key: list(set(dict1.get(key,[])+dict2.get(key,[])))
    for key in set(dict1)|set(dict2)}
```